# Reservation saving model

Tags: php, locking

I'm just wondering how I can solve the problem where in when inserting a new value, two instances are created at the same time? Some say use locking but both records are being inserted, not updated. Something like the code below.
The user is trying to reserve a seat in cinema, but two instance is created.

```
$cinema = new Cinema();
$cinema->seat = 'A';
$cinema->save();


$cinema = new Cinema();
$cinema->seat = 'A';
$cinema->save();
```

Comment: Make the email column `UNIQUE` in your database.

Comment: sorry my sample code is not really the example i want to say. but something like this $cinema->seat = 'A'; $cinema->save(); there will be two user in seat no A

Comment: i updated the sample code for reference.

Comment: `new` + `save`--> INSERT. `read from DB` + change + `save` --> UPDATE